# Write data to CSV file

Tags: c#, csv, file-io

I'm having a question about writing data to a CSV file.
I have a file named test.csv in which are 2 fields > accountnumber and relation ID.
Now I want to add another field next to it: IBAN.
**The IBAN is the data from the first row which is validated by the SOAP function BBANtoIBAN**.

How can I keep the 2 rows of data accountnumbers and relation IDs in the CSV and add the IBAN in the 3rd row?

This is my code so far:

```
using (var client = new WebService.BANBICSoapClient("IBANBICSoap"))
{
    List<List<string>> dataList = new List<List<string>>();
    TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(@"C:\CSV\test.csv");
    parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
    parser.SetDelimiters(";");
    while (!parser.EndOfData)
    {
        List<string> data = new List<string>();
        string row = parser.ReadLine();

        try
        {
            string resultIBAN = client.BBANtoIBAN(row);
            if (resultIBAN != string.Empty)
               data.Add(resultIBAN);
            else
               data.Add("Accountnumber is not correct.");
        }
        catch (Exception msg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(msg);
        }
        dataList.Add(data);
    }  
}
```

Comment: You can read file and each line add ";[yourIBANPropValue]"

Comment: How do you mean, in parser.Readline()? Is there any documentation or examples online so I can take a look at it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see it as:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\CSV\test.csv")
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\CSV\testOut.csv")
while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
{
    string line = sr.ReadLine(); 


try
{
       string[] rowsArray = line.Split(';');
       string row = rowsArray[0];
       string resultIBAN = client.BBANtoIBAN(row);
       if (resultIBAN != string.Empty)
       {
           line +=";"+ resultIBAN;
       }
       else
       {
            line +=";"+"Accountnumber is not correct.";
       }

 }
 catch (Exception msg)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(msg);
 }
 sw.WriteLine(line) 
 }
sr.Close();
sw.Close();
```

Comment: row is in this case line I guess?

Comment: Hm, I'll add some additional info, I forgot some things

Comment: The testOut.csv is created; but empty.

Comment: Are you add sr.Close() and sw.Close() ?

Comment: And it`s still empty? Have you message about exceptions?

Comment: Which data are you take to BBANtoIBAN()

Comment: I take the info of the first row, for example: first row contains 510-0075470-61 , second row is the ID: 21. Then I want to add the IBAN row with the created IBAN from the data of the first row

Comment: Ok. Try code  with last changes. As i understand you create IBAN with accountnumber.

Comment: Wow, yeah! This works! It adds the info to the 4th line, but that I can try to solve myself! I owe you a beer! :D

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this to parse the csv file, and add an extra item to the data list:

```
        List<List<string>> dataList = new List<List<string>>();
        string filename = @"C:\CSV\test.csv";
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
        {
            string fileContent = sr.ReadToEnd();

            foreach (string line in fileContent.Split(new string[] {Environment.NewLine},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                List<string> data = new List<string>();
                foreach (string field in line.Split(';'))
                {
                    data.Add(field);
                }
                try
                {
                    string resultIBAN = client.BBANtoIBAN(data[0]);
                    if (resultIBAN != string.Empty)
                    {
                        data.Add(resultIBAN);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        data.Add("Accountnumber is not correct.");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception msg)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(msg);
                }
                dataList.Add(data);
            }
```

Comment: Then 'row' in this case is 'field'? How can I validate the value of the first row into the function BBANtoIBAN and then add a 3rd row with the output of the function?

Comment: Sorry, didn't catch that.  You would pass in the first string in the List.